# How to pass django variable as parameter inside {% url %} tag?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a `view` function like this:

```
def view(request):
    x = 5
    y = 10

    context = {
        'x': x,
        'y': y,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and a `result` function like this:

```
def result(request, number):
    square = int(number) * int(number)
    return HttpResponse(str(square))
```

I am passing `context` from the `view` function to the `index.html` template, which looks like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>{{ str(x) }}</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'app:result' number=str(y) %}">Square it</a>
</body>
```

The template renders `x` successfully as a header, but I don't know how to pass `y` as the `number` parameter in the `result` view.

Comment: just `number=y` ( `"{% url 'app:result' number=y %}"`

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: What was the error message? Or what was the URL inserted into the HTML (inspect the link on the browser)? BTW I was assuming a named arg in the URL. If it's a positional arg, just use `"{% url 'app:result' y %}"

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple:

```
{% url 'app:result' y %}
```